# A simple graph with minimum degree larger than $\lceil n^{\frac{1}{k}} \rceil$ has a girth of at most $2k$.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Let $G$ be a simple undirected graph such that all of the nodes in $G$ has a degree larger than $\lceil n^{\frac{1}{k}} \rceil$.

How can you prove that the length of the shortest cycle in $G$ is at most $2k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove this by contradiction. Consider any arbitrary node $v$. Since there are no cycles of length $2k$, all simple paths starting at $v$ of length at most $k$ must end at different nodes. Since the degree of each node is larger than $n^{\frac{1}{k}}$, there are larger than $(n^{\frac{1}{k}})^k = n$ such paths. But this is a contradiction, since there are only $n$ nodes in the graph.